# cakephp : go to previous page after editing a player

Tags: php, cakephp, http-referer, referer

I have players in pages. I'm for instance on page 13. Here I click on the edit function to edit a player. Now after the edit I want to get back to that page 13 but It stays at the edit page.

edit action :

```
public function admin_edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Player->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid player'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $data = $this->request->data['Player'];
        if(!$data['player_image']['name']){
            unset($data['player_image']);
        }
        if ($this->Player->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The player has been saved.'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The player could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Player.' . $this->Player->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Player->find('first', $options);
    }
    $videos = $this->Player->Video->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('videos'));
}
```

view action :

```
public function admin_view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Player->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid player'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Player.' . $this->Player->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('player', $this->Player->find('first', $options));
}
```

Comment: you don't need to return the redirect, have you tried just `$this->redirect($this->referer())`? or debugging `$this->referer`, maybe it came from your same edit page and that's why it stays there (I can't know from the code you provided)

Comment: The 2 options you gave are giving me the same result :/

Comment: you are telling me that if you debug `$this->referer()` in `admin_edit`, you get `admin/controller/view/13`? I sincerely doubt that unless the save if failing.

Comment: I get admin/players/edit/58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the referring page in the `else` section of the `if/else` structure of the edit function. Then use that stored value in the `if` (i.e., `$this->request->is(array('post', 'put')) = TRUE` section.

So your code would look something like:

```
public function admin_edit($id = null) {
  if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

    /* your other code */

    $sendback = $this->Session->read('referer');
    $this->Session->delete('referer');
    $this->redirect($sendback);

  } else {

    /* your other code */

    $this->Session->write('referer', $this->referer());
  }
}
```