# how to return pagination on same page where it was before in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have used pagination to display surveylist in cakephp 2.x . Also i have given link to edit details of any survey.Now , when I edit any survey and redirect to surveylist ,the pagination returns the first page, I want pagination to return on the same page where it was before.Plzzz help me.....

**my code of editing survey is:-**

```
public function editsurvey($id){
  $dt=$this->Survey->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));
  // pr($dt['Survey']['no_of_ques']);exit;
  if($this->request->is(array('post','put'))){
      $data = $this->request->data['Survey'];
      // pr($data['no_of_ques']);exit;
      if($data['no_of_ques'] < $dt['Survey']['no_of_ques'] ){
          //pr("Which Questions you want to delete");
          //  $id=$dt['Survey']['id'];
          return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'deleteques',$id));
      }
      $this->Survey->id=$id;
      if($this->Survey->save($this->request->data)){
          $this->Flash->success(__('You have successfully updated survey'));
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'surveylist')); 
      }
  }else{
      $data=$this->Survey->findById($id);
      $this->request->data=$data;
  }
```

}

**action for surveylist is:-**

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
                                          'Survey' => array(
                                                        'limit' => 5,
                                                        'order' => 'created desc',
                                                        'conditions'=>array('is_deleted'=> 0)
                                                       )
                                       );
          $numbers = $this->Paginator->paginate('Survey');
          $this->set(compact('numbers'));
```

Comment: is the same of your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883791/i-want-to-return-on-same-page-in-cakephp-2-x-pagination-after-deleting-an-entry/46884649#46884649

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i want to return on same page in cakephp 2.x pagination after deleting an entry,by default it return on first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883791/i-want-to-return-on-same-page-in-cakephp-2-x-pagination-after-deleting-an-entry)

Comment: no sir,
if i use : $this->redirect($this->referer());
it redirect onto the form which appeared after clicking on edit button.
i think it:-$this->redirect($this->referer()); redirects on the page which is just previous to the current page
but
I need to redirect on the previous to previous page.
previous page is the form which appeared for editing 
and
previous to previous page is the surveylist displayed through pagination.

Comment: so you have to store the referer somewhere

Comment: okk sir,I'll try to do that.....

Comment: sir, can u give me some idea about storing referer somewhere.....i am not able to do that????????????

Comment: you can store it in the session, or pass it in the form see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652396/cakephp-go-to-previous-page-after-editing-a-player